# Opening app from push notification causes NullPointerException

Tags: codenameone

I have created an app using Codename One but I am having trouble with the push notifications on Android.

The issue happens when opening a push notification when the app isn't open in the background.

When it tries to use any resources from the theme it causes a NullPointerException. The theme is initialised in the init() method but doesn't appear to happen when opening the push notification.

If I then initialise the theme in the same method as the null pointer, just before it happens, it works. It then goes on to cause a null pointer further on in the method.

Why do some objects not appear to be initialised on android when opening a push notification when the app is not open in the background?

The line that originally causes the NullPointerException when using the theme is

```
Image icon = theme.getImage("ADINlogoRound.png");
```

My init method is

```
public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    Resources css = null;
    try {
        css = Resources.openLayered("/theme.css");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(css.getTheme(css.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

    Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
}
```

Comment: You should post the stacktrace and the code that is causing the NPE. It's hard to say what could be wrong otherwise.

Comment: I have added the code that causes the issue. I will try get the stacktrace that is displayed on the screen but this is difficult as the app is in production and can't be reproduced using the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in android the init and start methods are not called when the app is opened from a push notification. Whatever you do in those methods should also be done in the push method.

Comment: There are 3 basic cases where push can be invoked. Cold (app isn't running at all), background (app is minimized), foreground. All 3 have their own very platform dependent behaviors. You can't rely on the UI being there already for some push types and you need to guard against that. Notice that if the app is indeed coming to the foreground init/start will be invoked so you shouldn't just "redo" what's there. Instead you should store state data for the app initialization later on